# How to use the same recorder object repeatedly

Tags: android, video, illegalstateexception, android-mediarecorder

I am creating a MediaRecorder and using it to generate a video clip. It works perfectly the first time. I end the video shooting process by setting the maximum file size to 5MB, after which it enters the **onInfo** method and the completely that particular video snap.

Now I want to generate 5 such clips, one after the other. For which I add the following to the onInfo method:

```
@Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Reached onInfoListener");
        if(what==android.media.MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video clip "+video_count+" recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            recorder.stop(); //recorder is an object of type MediaRecorder
            recorder.reset();
            initRecorder();  //Reinitializing for subsequent video generation
                    prepareRecorder(); //Re preparing for subsequent video generation




        }
    }


 private void initRecorder() {

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);



        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"/FOLDERNAME");
        if(!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdir();
        }

             CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
                     .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
             recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);


        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/FOLDERNAME/video"+video_count+".mp4");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5*1048576); // Approximately 5 megabytes

    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraView.getHolder().getSurface());

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** *videocount* is a variable used to give a distinct name to each generated video clip.

However after successfully capturing the first video clip, and just before the second clip an start recording, a **IllegalStateException** is encountered when I try to start the recorder object again.   Since I am using **recorder.reset()** API, I thought that I would be able to reuse the *recorder* object for subsequent iterations. But it is giving this problem.

How to solve this issue? Is it neccessary to provide some delay after reinitializing the recorder object?

**EDIT:** If I keep the *recorder.start()* inside a button click, this works, that is, on every button click, a separate video is taken. But if I ask it to take say, 5 videos, on a single button click, the app crashes before it starts taking the second video, that is, it works only once. How to overcome this non-uniformity?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) you need to call the setOutputFormat() method before you can call prepare(), like this:

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```